# Magento unsecure and secure base_url settings in https only

Tags: magento-1.9, https

Magento 1.9 setup for https Only.

When the **UNsecure**_base_url is set to http**S** is it normal behaviour for Magento to ignore the UNsecure_base_url settings for media, skin and js and use the **secure**_base_url settings for these folders?

For Example:

`Base URL => https://mySecureSiteURL/`

`Base Skin URL => mySecureCDN-URL/skin`

`Base Media URL => mySecureCDN-URL/media`

`Base Java URL => mySecureCDN-URL/js`

`Secure Base URL => https://mySecureSiteURL/`

`Secure Base Skin URL => {{secure_base_url}}skin`

`Secure Base Media URL => {{secure_base_url}}media`

`Secure Base Java URL => {{secure_base_url}}js`

Magento only ever uses the Secure Base URL settings for non-sensitive pages (ie catagory, product and CMS) and ignores the Unsecure Base URL settings pointing to CDN. Is this Normal?

Answer (score 1):

Go to : `System > Configuration > Web > Secure` and make sure the following are set correctly :

- Base Link URL - `{{secure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL - `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL - `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
- Base Javascript URL - `{{secure_base_url}}js/`

With this, the paths generated will follow `"Base URL"`.  If a page is secure everything on it will also be served secure.

Comment: By doing this none of my pages will be served from the CDN.  If Magento's unsecure_base_url is set to  https  it ignores the unsecure url links and uses the secure links instead.

Comment: Is the behaviour as described in my previous comment Normal ?